# Finding the width of an NSString as a CGFloat

Tags: objective-c

I know that this has been posted already, but the solution i found

```
-(CGFloat)widthOfText{
    CGRect idealFrame = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:self.frame.size
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:self.font }
                                            context:nil];

    return idealFrame.size.width;
}
```

self is a UILabel

isn't working.

I'm trying to place a button at the end of a string so I need the width of the string to calculate the buttons absolute placement

can anybody explain why this isn't working or suggest a different method?

Comment: What about this isn't working?

Comment: Regardless of the content of text it returns the same number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or more of the inputs is not what you expect, `NSLog()` `self.text`, `self.frame`, `self.font` -- basic debugging.

It is really better to pass in parameters than use ivars, this allows easier testing. It also removes the dependency on the class.

Example that works properly:

```
NSString *text = @"1235";
CGSize frameSize = CGSizeMake(300, 50);
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

CGRect idealFrame = [text boundingRectWithSize:frameSize
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                    attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font }
                                       context:nil];
NSLog(@"width: %0.1f", idealFrame.size.width);
```